# How should I approach the Beck manga, having watched the entire anime adaptation?

Tags: beck

I just finished the Beck anime and I want to continue the story from the manga. Do I need to start from the beginning of the manga, or is there any specific volume/chapter I can pick up from? Also, are there any significant differences between the manga (source material) and the anime adaptation, that would require me to start over if i were to start reading the manga?